# Getting ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Getting ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception in debezium , using it for mysql connector

```
{"requestId" : "", "level" : "ERROR", "time" : "2020-04-06T15:00:41.086Z", "thread" : "pool-65-thread-1", "class" : "i.d.e.EmbeddedEngine", "line" : "467", "message" : "Error while trying to run connector class 'io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector'"}
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: 1
    at io.debezium.connector.mysql.AbstractReader.wrap(AbstractReader.java:164)
    at io.debezium.connector.mysql.AbstractReader.failed(AbstractReader.java:142)
    at io.debezium.connector.mysql.BinlogReader.handleEvent(BinlogReader.java:332)
    at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.notifyEventListeners(BinaryLogClient.java:902)
    at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.listenForEventPackets(BinaryLogClient.java:760)
    at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.connect(BinaryLogClient.java:472)
    at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient$5.run(BinaryLogClient.java:657)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at io.debezium.relational.TableSchemaBuilder.lambda$createValueGenerator$3(TableSchemaBuilder.java:226)
    at io.debezium.relational.TableSchema.valueFromColumnData(TableSchema.java:111)
    at io.debezium.connector.mysql.RecordMakers$1.update(RecordMakers.java:235)
    at io.debezium.connector.mysql.RecordMakers$RecordsForTable.update(RecordMakers.java:444)
    at io.debezium.connector.mysql.BinlogReader.handleUpdate(BinlogReader.java:573)
    at io.debezium.connector.mysql.BinlogReader.handleEvent(BinlogReader.java:319)
```

Table structure of source , I do not why I am getting this : Please let me know when I am supposed to get this error .............................................................................

```
     `table_test` (
      `test_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `report_code` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
      `transfer_type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `transfer_component` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
      `amount` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
      `user_id` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
      `status` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
      `client_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
      `request_transaction_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `transaction_type` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
      `external_flag` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      `check_id_new` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
 `properties` json DEFAULT NULL,
      `remitter_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      `remitter_mobile` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
      `test_account` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
      `remitter_ifsc` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
      `beneficiary_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      `test_name_three` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
      `test_name_four` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
      `test_name_two` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      `channel_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
      `channel_id` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
      `remarks` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `ext_transaction_id` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
      `ext_response_code` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
      `rrn` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
      `stan` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
      `response_code` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      `user_agent` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `extra_info` varchar(1023) DEFAULT NULL,
      `check` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
      `initiated_by` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
      `created_date` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `updated_date` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `settlement_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`test_id`),
      KEY `client_transaction_request_id` (`request_transaction_id`,`client_name`),
      KEY `user_id_index` (`user_id`),
      KEY `beneficiary_account_no_index` (`beneficiary_account_no`),
      KEY `created_date_index` (`created_date`),
      KEY `test_account_index` (`test_account`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Config for debezium ................................................................................................................................................................................:

```
{
  "replicationConfigs" : [
    {
      "id" : 1,
      "serviceId" : "testdb-service",
      "method" : "debezium",
      "config" : {
        "connector.class" : "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
        "name" : "mysql-connector",
        "database.hostname" : "dburl",
        "database.port" : 3306,
        "database.user" : "user_test",
        "database.password" : "passwordtest",
        "database.whitelist" : "testdb",
        "table.whitelist" : ["testdb.table_test"],
        "database.server.name" : "bank",
        "include.schema.changes" : "true",
        "database.history" : "io.debezium.relational.history.KafkaDatabaseHistory",
        "database.history.kafka.topic" : "testdb.history.table_test",
        "database.history.kafka.partitions" : 1,
        "database.history.kafka.replication.factor" : 1,
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers" : "ip detail",
        "offset.storage" : "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.KafkaOffsetBackingStore",
        "offset.storage.topic" : "testdb.offset.table_test",
        "offset.storage.partitions" : 1,
        "offset.storage.replication.factor" : 1,
        "bootstrap.servers" : "ip detail",
        "internal.key.converter" : "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "internal.value.converter" : "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "snapshot.mode":"schema_only"
      },
      "isPicked" : false,
      "isActive" : true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What version of Debezium are you running? What do your source table DDL look like, and source connector config?

Comment: 0.5.0 version of debezium

Comment: @RobinMoffatt when this error supposed to occur

Comment: What do your source table DDL look like, and source connector config?

Comment: Try updating your version of Debezium - latest is 1.1, 0.5 is *very* old.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt can it be because of binlog-row-image = minimal

Comment: What do your source table DDL look like, and source connector config?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt table structure is given above , please check

Comment: @RobinMoffatt please help here

Comment: Does it work if you use the latest version of Debezium (1.1) ?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt  have updated to 0.7.2  but still getting error

Comment: The latest version is 1.1.